# CSS or jQuery make content center vertically on zoom out

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have not been able to figure out how to center content vertically as the user zooms out. [image]

I have 3 divs, and as they are zoomed out on, they stick towards the top rather than staying centered as seen here: [image]

The blue is just the background of the 2nd div. I need them to center vertically rather than sticking at the top as the user zooms out. (Cntrl/cmd -)

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(window).height()` to get the the height of the viewport. Use something like:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  var ht = $(window).height()/2-$('#theGroupContainer').height()/2+'px';
  $('#theGroupContainer').css({top: ht});
})
```

Make sure:

```
body{
  position:relative;
}
#theGroupContainer{
  position:absolute;
}
```

Use `%` for `#theGroupContainer` children `height` and `width`.

Comment: The only issue is that, I have elements below what is demonstrated, so I cannot make theGRoupContainer absolute, or else the rest of the page flow moves over it. 

(the rest of the elements stay below the viewable initial screen until the user begins to scroll)

that part is controlled by this: 

$(document).ready(function(){
    var height = $(window).height(); 
    $('.footer').css('height', height - 420 + 'px');
});

Answer (score 0):

Do you want them to move center as the user zooms out? I don't know but you can probably use javascript to add margin as the page zooms out but by default pages stick to the top.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up dynamically changing the size of the top element:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var height = $(window).height(); 
    console.log($(window).height());
    $('.header').css('padding-top', height*.4 - 240 + 'px');
});
```